# Inject javascript in existing asp.net webforms app

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am currently working on a website which has a lot of javascript . How can i make sure that my javascript has the best chance of running properly? By adding another script section in the page or through asp.net registering the script?

Comment: The best chance of running properly? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by "javascript has the best chance of running properly" ?

Comment: whether your script will work will depend on what other javascripts are there already. Because I did not build the site from scratch I dont know what other js I can interfere with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478975.aspx

By using the RegisterStartupScript() method on the server side Page_Load you can ensure that all of your HTML markup is loaded and ready to be modified. It is also good practice to put your javascript  sections at the bottom of your form's markup if you want to access html elements, for example setting a textboxes text or something.

You can't really say one is "better" or has a "better chance of running properly" than the other, because you would use either/or depending on what you need to do. If you read the above link that I posted I think things will make a lot more sense for ya.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use ASP.NET to register the script if you're making changes to it server side. Other than that, put it in the `<head>` section.